# Is C++ whole program optimization done in gcc if I set optimization -O3?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, gcc

I'm wondering if whole program optimization is done if I just specify optimization level 3 in gcc (version 4.8.1 running on Ubuntu 12.04) or if I have to explicitly specify whole program optimization as a gcc option?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-fwhole-program` (and `-flto`) are *not* automatically set by any `-O` options.
Source: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html . Options that are part of an `-O` optimization level are marked as such in there, and there is also a list of enabled options for each `-O`.

Comment: Notice also that it's likely that you want `-flto`, not `-fwhole-program`.

Comment: Fair point. `-flto` isn't automatically set either, edited my answer accordingly.